# Get JSON from AJAX to use in jqplot

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, charts, jqplot

I've been trying to populate an array which is to be used in the jquery jqplot plugin/extension.

From what I can tell my two different JSON objects/arrays are identical in the structure, but only the "static" one is working as expected.
I've seen similar questions on stackoverflow but none of which have been been working for me.

I've checked to see if there are any whitespaces returned in the source of the get_chart_votes but there's nothing that I can find.
Using the latest CodeIgniter framwork, jQuery and jqplot.

When using the static $arr I can alert the results to get [Object object] but when trying to do the same with the $charArray I get nothing.

When the static $arr is returned, it prints this json

```
{"test":1,"test2":2,"test3":3}
```

With mysql results in $chartArray is returned, it prints this json

```
{"Yes":1,"No":2,"Maybe":6}
```

My PHP code (with the $chartArray echo commented out)

```
function get_chart_votes()
{

    $arr = array('test' => 1, 'test2' => 2, 'test3' => 3);
    die(json_encode($arr));

    $chartArray = array();
    $post = $this->input->post();
    $id = $post['id'];

    $answers  = $this->get_answers($id)->result_array();
    $votes = $this->get_votes($id)->result_array();

    $count = 0;
    $answer = 1;
    foreach($answers[0] as $ans)
    {
        if($count > 1 && $ans != "")
        {
            $vote = $votes[$answer-1]['COUNT(vote)'];
            $chartArray[$ans] = intval($vote);
            $answer++;
        }
        $count++;
    }
    //echo(json_encode($chartArray));
}
```

On the client side I've got this.

```
var s1 = [];
var ticks = [];
$.getJSON(
"../votr/get_chart_votes",
{ id: "57"},
function(jsonData) 
{
    for (var key in jsonData) 
    {
      if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) 
      {
        s1.push(jsonData[key]);
        ticks.push(key);
      }
    }

    $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;

    plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [s1], {
        // Only animate if we're not using excanvas (not in IE 7 or IE 8)..
        animate: !$.jqplot.use_excanvas,
        seriesDefaults:{
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: { show: true }
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks
            }
        },
        highlighter: { show: true }
    });


    $('#chart1').bind('jqplotDataHighlight',
        function (ev, seriesIndex, pointIndex, data) {
            $('#info1').html(ticks[pointIndex] + " got " + s1[pointIndex]);
        }
    );

}
);
```